# OpenApi generator Mustache logic

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

Where can you find all open API `mustache` logic?
like "`httpMethod`" or "`Operations`", the only way I found is by looking at an example.
But some logic isn't clear anyway I still don't understand how to use "`requestBody`" or if there is a way to make a section dependent on the `httpMethod`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you trying to learn mustache templating?  If so, there are plenty of resources available.  The [official documentation](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) is probably a good start.  Are you trying to learn how the templates are created?  Check the [TemplateManager](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen).  Are you trying to see how the `httpMethod` is set?  Check `DefaultCodegen.java` at same link above.  Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: i want to know if there is a list of all special tags set by openapi-generator.

Comment: Unfortunately,, there is no single list available of all special tags.  A quick check shows there are currently 169 different generators, each of which uses some form of its own mustache templates.  Each template will have different tags depending on a wide range of things; from the language selected to the configOptions passed to it.